# WP Super Cache: create cached files of all the pages

Tags: wordpress, wget, browser-cache, cache-control

I'm using [WP Super Cache](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-super-cache/) as the hosting recommends.

I guess that WP Super Cache creates a cached file the first time somebody visit a page of the website. I want to cach all the files at once, so my idea is to open all the pages of the site.

I wonder if I download the entire website with `wget`, all the pages will be cached.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WP Super Cache has a "preload" mode which you can find under it's settings. It's exactly what your searching for and does what you say it does, it simply "simulates" a page visit.

Comment: So quick answer! Thanks :)